Strange buds / growths on indoor cactus
I was given a cactus by a friend recently and it has developed a series of pink / red buds or growths which can be seen (highlighted) in the pictures below:


Can anyone advise what these buds or growths are?
They appear randomly on the limbs of the cactus but are easily removed. I am curious to know if they are a parasite of other infestation. The cactus flowers in the spring time and I know it to be several years old and otherwise healthy.

Are they flower buds?

No. The flowers appear in spring rather than late summer. These buds or growths are separate.

Googling about Mammillaria elongata, they could be the fruits. In fact looking better, I may see some other old flowers, (Note: flowers can appear all years along, especially if the plant was moved (and/or was stressed)).

These look like fruit - the flower buds of most Mamillarias are usually shorter, nestled amongst the spines.

Yes, they are fruit as indicated by https://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/268427.
I must try planting a few of them.

As far as I can see its flower buds there can be a possibility that they can grow in late summer.
